# Convert CSV to Bytes-like Object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a dataframe and I'm changing that datafram to csv using

```
new_csv = df.to_csv()
```

Now i want to convert this new_csv into bytes object . When I try this:

```
new_bytes_obj = io.BytesIO(new_csv)
```

I get an error :

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str

Any way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by bytes-like object??

Comment: @U11-Forward  getting this error while doing this  new_bytes_obj = io.BytesIO(new_csv)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str

Comment: @ankursuman: the good question is why you need a bytes like object. You could just use `new_str_obj = io.StringIO(new_csv)`. If you need bytes, you can convert a string to bytes with `encode`: `new_bytes_obj = io.BytesIO(new_csv.encode())`.

Comment: @ankursuman strings are converted to bytes with [str.encode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20encode#str.encode) . The default encoding is UTF-8. Python strings are Unicode so UTF-8 is the best optiono

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question why you want a BytesIO object. The natural and obvious and usually correct solution for textual data is to encapsulate it in a StringIO object instead.

```py
new_str_obj = io.StringIO(new_csv)
```

If you need BytesIO, your `str` data needs to be converted to `bytes` data instead. In this case, you need to decide how to encode your string; if you don't know, UTF-8 is often a good guess, but you probably should spend some time on understanding what this actually means for your specific application.

```py
new_bytes_obj = io.BytesIO(new_csv.encode('utf-8'))
```

Probably read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and/or Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) now rather than later.